# Insert row by using loop with condition

Tags: sql-server

I have `tbl_emp` like that:

```
empid
1  
2
3
4
```

And `tbl_att` like that:

```
empid     workingdate
1         2017-05-11
2         2017-05-13
3         2017-05-14
...........
...........
```

I have a job in SQL Server agent to execute step every Sunday and I want that job to insert a row for each `empid` with that day into `tbl_att`. Let's say Sunday is 2017-05-22 so I want it like that:

```
empid     workingdate
1         2017-05-22
2         2017-05-22
3         2017-05-22
```

It means that I want it to insert into `tbl_att` for all `empid` with the same day (task execution day), so can anyone guide me a query that I need to put into my step command?

Comment: Sounds like a simple update statement

Comment: The row is not yet exist, how can we use update statement?

Comment: If it doesnt exist... why are the dates different?

Comment: it's a previous data, and what i want is to insert new row to table for every Sunday, not update the existed record to Sunday bro/sis.

Comment: What insert statement you tried? Did it insert the record? What error did you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into tbl_att (empid, workingdate)
Select empid,cast(getdate() as date) from tbl_emp
```

As you run the job on every Sunday, above query will insert the data as per your expectation I believe. FYI, But it depends on the system date

Comment: But can you explain me about this line of query?

Comment: Getdate will fetch the current system date. As you're running on sunday, it will fetch the Sundays equivalent system date.

Comment: Thanks you for your explanation

Comment: How would you eliminate the duplicate records not to be inserted

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
INSERT INTO tbl_att SELECT empid,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) FROM tbl_emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl_att (empid INT,workingdate DATE)

CREATE TABLE #EmpidTab (empid INT)

INSERT INTO #EmpidTab
SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4
SELECT * FROM #EmpidTab

INSERT INTO #EmpidTab
SELECT 5

INSERT INTO #tbl_att
SELECT Empid
    ,Getdate() AS workingdate
FROM #EmpidTab i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #tbl_att t
        WHERE t.empid = i.Empid
        ) --Eliminate duplicte insertion of empid's 

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS NoRowsInserted

SELECT *
FROM #tbl_att
```